# Regular expression for words not starting or ending with vowels?

Tags: regex, regular-language

I used this regex: `^[aeiou](\w|\s)*[aeiou]$` 
for words starting and ending with vowels and it works fine.

But when I use this regex:
`^[^aeiou](\w|\s)*[^aeiou]$` for words not starting and ending with vowels, it doesn't work. Can you tell me what is wrong in my 2nd regex?

**Words are like:**
South Britain
Rives Junction
Larkspur
Southport
Compton
Linden
Sedgwick
Humeston
Siler
Panther Burn

Comment: Is your regex engine case-insensitive? `[A] != [a]`

Comment: yes I have applied the case-insensitive modifier

Comment: Those work for me. Can you post the code you are using to test these? What language?

Comment: Actually i am trying to solve this: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-11

Comment: i am running this query `select distinct(city) from station where regexp_like(city, '^[^aeiou](\w|\s)*[^aeiou]$', 'i');` which is oracle based.

Comment: the 2nd regex doesn't work here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-11 but the 1st regex works here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-8

Comment: @AntaraRoy Please edit the question to clarify the question, so it matches the problem statement at the challenge site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct(city) from station
  WHERE regexp_like(city, '^[^aeiou](\w|\s)*$', 'i')
    OR regexp_like(city, '^(\w|\s)*[^aeiou]$', 'i');
```

The question is asking "ends with OR starts with" you can do it in the regex, but I did it as an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: i used this: `^([^aeiou](\w|\s)*)|((\w|\s)*[^aeiou])$`

Comment: That works. I was trying to get that to work in regexr.com, but I think you have to take into account a `\r` character before the `$`, and it was getting messy.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the desired logic and if you happen to want a single regular expression, I would use something like `!/(^[aeiou](\w|\s)*)|((\w|\s)*[aeiou]$)/i`.  This, of course, is not the most readable format, but should grab only those words that start AND end with non-vowels.

Comment: @Antara Roy -- I just saw your comment to bradlis7, where you take a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game but if it’s MySQL this is what works for me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION 
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(CITY,'[aeiou]$','i') 
OR NOT REGEXP_LIKE(CITY, '^[aeiou]','i');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and readable solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM station
WHERE city NOT REGEXP '^[aeiou]' AND city NOT REGEXP '[aeiou]$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the simplest MS SQL Server command that you can come up with -

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY LIKE '[^aeiouAEIOU]%' OR CITY LIKE '%[^aeiouAEIOU]';
```

it can not get simpler than this.

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL I used:

```
Select distinct City from STATION where City RLike "^[^aeiou].*|[^aeiou]$"
```